# Can't connect to redis via Jedis over ssh tunnel

Tags: java, networking, redis, jedis

I have two machines: machine foo (`10.0.0.1`) is running a redis server, and machine bar (`192.168.0.1`) is running a java application connecting to foo via jedis.  Everything works fine when giving jedis the address `10.0.0.1`.

But I don't trust the routers between foo and bar, and redis doesn't support ssl. So I set up an ssh tunnel from bar to foo: `user@bar$ ssh -N -f -L localhost:6379:localhost:6379 user@foo`

Now, from bar, I can successfully telnet to redis on foo either directly at `10.0.0.1` or over the tunnel at `127.0.0.1`.  With jedis, if I use `127.0.0.1` I get the exception `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`, but jedis can successfully connect to `10.0.0.1` just fine.

How can I convince jedis to use the ssh tunnel?

Comment: Try replacing the two "localhost" instances in that command with the addresses in question and see if that works.

Comment: For the sake of experimentation, I tried changing the ssh command to `ssh -N -f -L *:6379:10.0.0.1:6379 user@foo`. It doesn't seem to have made any difference, which isn't surprising since I have confirmed that the ssh tunnel is working with telnet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The java app that is using jedis is a clustered application, and I had confused myself about which part of the application was launching jedis. Once I started the ssh tunnel on the master host rather than a slave, it all worked as expected.